# How to use Electron API with Vue js component?

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm using the [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) boilerplate, and I want to make my `mainWindow` a `fullScreen` after clicking a button.

Electron Window API: electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window

HTML:

```html
<button @click="setFullScreen">Switch to Full Screen</button>
```

Vue:

```js
export default {
  name: 'mainComponent',
  methods: {
    setFullScreen: function() {
      mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
    }
  }
```

This is not working. How can I use the Electron API in electron-vue?

and the index.js:

```js
'use strict'

import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
let mainWindow
const winURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? `http://localhost:${require('../../../config').port}`
  : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`
    
function createWindow () {
  /**
   * Initial window options
   */
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 728,
    width: 1024,
    fullscreen: false,
  })
    
  mainWindow.loadURL(winURL)
 
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
    
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('mainWindow opened')
}
    
app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

you will find it as it is in electron-Vue

the picture shows How the Structure of the folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb9O3.png)

Comment: where are you defining `mainWindow`?

Comment: in index.js, check i have updated the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mainWindow` is not available in your Vue code because it is defined in your main process.

In your single file component, however, you can import `remote` from electron, where you can get access to the current window. So your code would look something like this.

```js
const {remote} = require("electron")

export default {
  name: 'mainComponent',
  methods: {
    setFullScreen: function() {
      remote.getCurrentWindow().setFullScreen(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the alternative for this, as remote has been deprecated? I seen I should do main.js I should add `global.api.myFunc`. but main.ts is not the same as main.js for vue.

Comment: @WORMSS https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer is probably the way to go. I am going to test this myself as I have the same requirements.
I am using vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder though.

Comment: @Benargee I ended up doing (simplied) `// Vue side
window.require('electron').ipcRenderer.invoke('loadFile', filePath);

// background.js before createWindow()
import { ipcMain } from 'electron';
ipcMain.handle('loadFile', (_, filePath) => require('fs').promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8'))`